# I am getting -nan output in awk file while dividing two integers

Tags: awk

Code:

```
BEGIN {
    sent=0;
    received=0;
    event=$1;
}
{
    if(event=="s") sent++;
    else if(event=="r") received++;
}
END {
    printf "\n Packet Delivery Ratio: %.2f ", (sent/received)*100;
}
```

Output:

Packet Delivery Ratio: -nan

I want to remove -nan and display the correct output.

Comment: Dividing `0/0`?

Comment: or 1/0. Try If (received>0) printf "\n Packet Delivery Ratio: %.2f ", (sent/received)*100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `event` variable in the `BEGIN` block, so it doesn't get the value that corresponds to the current line. Move the assignment to the middle block:

```
BEGIN {
    sent=0;
    received=0;
}
{
    event=$1;
    if(event=="s") sent++;
    else if(event=="r") received++;
}
END {
    printf "Packet Delivery Ratio: %.2f\n", (received/sent)*100;
}
```

Note that the script can be written a bit more idiomatically like this:

```
{ event = $1 }
event == "s" { sent++ }
event == "r" { received++ }
END {
    printf "Packet Delivery Ratio: %.2f\n", (received/sent)*100
}
```

Also notice that the formula for the packet delivery ratio was incorrect. You should divide received / sent to get the correct value.

Comment: And you need to protect against divide by zero with `(sent ? (received/sent)*100 : 0)` or similar. The whole script can be reduced to just: `{event[$1]++}
    END{printf("\n Packet Delivery Ratio: %.2f ", (event["s"] ? (event["r"]/event["s"])*100 : 0)}`,

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it simpler:

```
($1=="s"){sent++}
($1=="r"){received++}
END{printf("\n Packet Delivery Ratio: %.2f ", (received/sent)*100)}
```